# table is --- is full mysql

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7 on windows'12 server, table which I am getting error crossed 2 GB in size, server memory is 4 Gb, MySQL used about 90% of memory..
Now any insertion into this table causing table full

Once I restarted MySQL works fine until the above stats come up it again starts giving exception. I am not a server guy, so need suggestions what would be the best solution here?

Comment: Which version of MySQL exactly? And what is the exact error?

Comment: Are you sure that you have sufficient disk space?

Comment: Is it a 32-bit version of MySQL?  Of Windows'12?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`

Comment: disk space of 266 GB, running MySQL 5.7, after restarted MySQL service the error gone may be a buffer or memory not enough to write into table?

Answer (score 1):

from the [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/full-table.html):

> If a table-full error occurs, it may be that the disk is full or that
>   the table has reached its maximum size. The effective maximum table
>   size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system
>   constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits

Also check the [Section C.10.3, “Limits on Table Size”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html)

Highlight for the OS limits.

```
+------------------------+------------------------------+
|    Operating System    |       File-size Limit        |
+------------------------+------------------------------+
| Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32     | 2GB/4GB                      |
| Win32 w/ NTFS          | 2TB (possibly larger)        |
| Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit | 2GB (LFS: 4GB)               |
| Linux 2.4+             | (using ext3 file system) 4TB |
| Solaris 9/10           | 16TB                         |
| OS X w/ HFS+           | 2TB                          |
+------------------------+------------------------------+
```

And the list under "If you do encounter a full-table error, there are several reasons why it might have occurred:"